# Accessing a dataframe using an index vs. using a variable in R

Tags: r, excel, indexing, dataframe

I have two ways to access data from an excel file. The first method is the easy way:

```
easy.way <- read.csv(file="flanker1.csv",header=TRUE)
```

The other is with an index:

```
file.number <- c(1)
index.way <-setNames(lapply(paste0("flanker", file.number,".csv"),read.csv),paste0(file.number,'participant'))
```

Both outputs look the same (I can't post a picture because my reputation is too low).The issue occurs when I try to access data. For example:

```
length(test$block) # length = 400, works
length(data[1]$block) # length = 0, doesn't work
```

Why is it that I can't access information about the data frame by using an index, but there is no problems if I use a standard variable?

Edit:

str(test):

```
'data.frame':   400 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ trial               : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ distractor.direction: int  2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ target.direction    : int  1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ fixcross.time       : int  2 1 2 3 2 4 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ intertrial.interval : int  2 1 1 2 1 4 3 3 4 1 ...
 $ type                : Factor w/ 2 levels "congruent","incongruent": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ keypress            : Factor w/ 2 levels "['a']","['l']": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ accuracy            : Factor w/ 2 levels "correct","incorrect": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ rt                  : num  0.325 0.433 0.359 0.315 0.501 ...
 $ block               : Factor w/ 2 levels "delay","no delay": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

str(data[1]):

```
List of 1
$ 1 participant:'data.frame':   400 obs. of  10 variables:
..$ trial               : int [1:400] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
..$ distractor.direction: int [1:400] 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
..$ target.direction    : int [1:400] 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
..$ fixcross.time       : int [1:400] 2 1 2 3 2 4 2 2 2 2 ...
..$ intertrial.interval : int [1:400] 2 1 1 2 1 4 3 3 4 1 ...
..$ type                : chr [1:400] "incongruent" "incongruent" "incongruent" "incongruent" ...
..$ keypress            : chr [1:400] "['a']" "['a']" "['a']" "['a']" ...
..$ accuracy            : chr [1:400] "incorrect" "correct" "correct" "incorrect" ...
..$ rt                  : num [1:400] 0.325 0.433 0.359 0.315 0.501 ...
..$ block               : chr [1:400] "delay" "delay" "delay" "delay" ...
```

Comment: Could you provide a consistent example? It's not clear what you try to access with length(). Also, what does Str() return for both ways?

Comment: Probably  `data[1]` does not have 'block' as a name. What does `str(data[1])` show you? This question is pretty much incoherent because neither test nor data have been defined or described in any manner.

Comment: I think you need to acess the element of the list in `data` . Does `data[[1]]$block` work. Note the double bracket  `[[`

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that - thanks. If you want to add it to the answer section, I'll give you the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the double bracket notation. `data[[1]]$block` should work